# Esto se hace con keyframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me gustaría saber si la forma gris que se mueve, la que esta detrás en el fondo esta hecha con keyframes o si no es así como esta hecha, gracias.

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/softlab-startup-and-app-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/23373445?_ga=2.214497879.1759328477.1571722557-1969728026.1563428903

Comment: ¿Has inspeccionado el código para comprobarlo? Lo he realizado y es un SVG que utiliza [elementos animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate).

Comment: Hola gracias @ElChiniNet estuve mirando pero no vi nada de svg, pero me parece super compleja de hacer, alguna sugerencia? se puede poner como fondo ??

Comment: No es complejo, mira el ejemplo básico en MDN para que veas cómo funciona. En el caso del ejemplo que has puesto, en `attributeName` han puesto `d` que hace referencia a la forma del [path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) con [una lista de values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/values). Creo que lo conseguirás reproducir, pero si no, puedes mejorar la pregunta para preguntar exactamente eso y podría colocarte un ejemplo como respuesta.

Comment: Pero tendria que hacer primero en Illustrator y guardar el código SVG? y ya luego animarlo? @ElChiniNet

Comment: Esa podría ser una opción si el `path` es complejo, sino puedes hacerlo directamente con los comandos de dibujo de ese elemento.

Comment: vale ya tengo hecho un dibujo parecido al de la web esa, pero algo más rápido, como animo eso ahora?? Necesitas que cambie la pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno por si alguien le sirve, gracias a los comentarios del compañero he podido sacar los mismo.

```html
<svg class="svgForma" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 180 180" data-stylerecorder="true">
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%" data-stylerecorder="true" style="text-align: inherit; line-height: 22px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 20px; border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-style: none; margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <image href="" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" data-stylerecorder="true" style="text-align: inherit; line-height: 22px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 20px; border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-style: none; margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px;"></image>
    </pattern>
    <path d="M 6.5 39.4 C 7.80365 62.5692 5.91007 81.182 3.8 94.8 c -2.77474 18.3873 -6.73752 31.3625 0.721167 42.0863 c 6.01562 8.45504 15.7771 10.6435 18.5121 11.0825 c 18.5584 4.29445 27.1796 -8.77372 63.9839 -26.1072 c 24.9898 -11.8133 38.1199 -14.1826 43.7552 -28.5139 c 3.11606 -8.01241 2.15051 -15.1844 1.82759 -17.4477 c -2.50088 -12.867 -14.1261 -22.3175 -28.121 -30.7115 c -20.1317 -12.4753 -40.3327 -47.5806 -71.878 -44.5705 C 29.3345 0.821168 21.6321 1.61474 15.2486 7.46569 C 3.36701 18.018 6.03212 36.639 6.5 39.4 Z" data-stylerecorder="true" style="text-align: inherit; line-height: 22px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 20px; border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-style: none; margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px;">
     <animate repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d" dur="10s" values="
     M6.5,39.4C7.9,62.9,6,81.5,3.8,94.8c-2.9,17.7-7.2,30.9,0.4,41.9c5.9,8.5,15.7,11,17.6,11.5
     c17.9,4.5,26.2-9.4,64-27c25.6-11.9,39.7-13.9,45.3-28c3.1-7.9,1.9-15.3,1.5-17.3c-2.7-12.7-14.2-21.9-28.5-30.4
     c-20-12-39.7-48.3-72-45.2C29.1,0.5,21.6,1.3,15.3,7C3.2,17.7,6,36.7,6.5,39.4z;
    
     M6.5,39.4C7.9,62.9,6,81.5,3.8,94.8c-4.1,24.8-5.6,33.6,0.4,41.9c10.6,14.8,41.6,17.2,56,4.3
     c11.2-9.9,4.2-21.5,15.8-31c13.8-11.4,29.9,0.5,45-12.3c9-7.6,11.1-18.4,11.7-21.9c2.5-17.1-9-30.9-16.7-40.1
     C92.4,7.4,57-3,32.2,0.2C25,1.1,19.7,3.1,15.3,7C3.2,17.7,6,36.7,6.5,39.4z;    
     M6.5,39.4C4.9,52.6,3.2,71.6,3.8,94.8c1,39.1,7.2,45.3,10.4,47.7c9.5,7.1,18.1-0.1,46-1.5
     c38.4-1.9,56.7,10.1,63.5,0.8c6.6-9.2-9.5-22.7-2.8-44c3.6-11.4,9.7-11.7,11.7-21.9c3.5-17.9-11.9-34.9-16.7-40.1
     C91.8,9,56.5,9.9,47.7,10.2c-11.3,0.3-25.1,0.9-34,11.3C8.4,27.6,7,34.8,6.5,39.4z;
    
     M6.5,39.4C7.9,62.9,6,81.5,3.8,94.8c-2.9,17.7-7.2,30.9,0.4,41.9c5.9,8.5,15.7,11,17.6,11.5
     c17.9,4.5,26.2-9.4,64-27c25.6-11.9,39.7-13.9,45.3-28c3.1-7.9,1.9-15.3,1.5-17.3c-2.7-12.7-14.2-21.9-28.5-30.4
     c-20-12-39.7-48.3-72-45.2C29.1,0.5,21.6,1.3,15.3,7C3.2,17.7,6,36.7,6.5,39.4z  " data-stylerecorder="true" style="text-align: inherit; line-height: 22px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 20px; border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-style: none; margin: 0px; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        </animate>
    </path>
</svg>
```